# Atom can't find discord and asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot and I can't even get it online!
I can't find a way to install discord.py and asyncio..

I'm using a mac and when I run "python3 -m pip install -U discord.py" I get a "Requirement already up-to-date" message which probably means I have discord.py but ATOM can't find it.

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = "*token*"

prefix = "."
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)


@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

This code with discord.py installed in my computer should work in theory and I don't know why it doesn't..

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Your IDE is probably using a different python installation than the one you ran `pip` with.

Comment: I run the code on terminal (with an extension) and I get this error:
"line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ImportError: No module named discord"